# How to convert low level code from TF 1 to TF 2

Tags: tensorflow

I want to initialize weights and biases from a normal distribution in TF 2 to be similar to TF 1.

I cant seem to find the tf.truncated_normal in the API for TF 2.

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, channels_in, channels_out], stddev = 0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [channels_out])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random number operations are now in `tf.random`. So you just need to use `tf.random.truncated_normal`.